# Alternativa de IF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera saber una alternativa para evitar el uso execesivo de IF dentro de este código

```
if (paq.Lunes)
    this.lu.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Martes)
    this.ma.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Miercoles)
    this.mi.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Jueves)
    this.jue.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Viernes)
    this.vie.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Sabado)
    this.sa.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
if (paq.Domingo)
    this.dom.Attributes.Add("class", "select");

if (!paq.aplicaTransporte)
    this.transporte.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaEntrada)
    this.entrada.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaGuia)
    this.guia.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaComida)
    this.comida.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaSeguro)
    this.seguro.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaTransporteMaritimo)
    this.maritimo.Visible = false;
if (!paq.aplicaBebidasAlcoholicas)
    this.alcohol.Visible = false;
```

Esta es la clase

```
public class PaqueteTour
{
public Boolean Lunes { get; set; }
    public Boolean Martes { get; set; }
    public Boolean Miercoles { get; set; }
    public Boolean Jueves { get; set; }
    public Boolean Viernes { get; set; }
    public Boolean Sabado { get; set; }
    public Boolean Domingo { get; set; }
{
        //
        // TODO: Agregar aquí la lógica del constructor
        //
        precio = new preciotourlistado();
        promocion = new PromoHotel();
    }
}
```

Estoy trabajando en .NET C#, he pensado en usar funciones como el `.map` o alguno de esos pero no encuentro la forma de implementarlo, pues esta información viene de una API.

Comment: Si Lunes, Martes, etc es un enum, puedes usar un switch.

Comment: Pregunta: De que tipo son las propiedades: `this.lun`, `this.mar` , etc. Y en el segundo grupo de `if`s que pasa cuando si se cumpel la condición, el valor de la propiedad a actualizar debería ser `true` ?

Comment: las propiedades this.lu etc, son elementos del html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una alternativa a los if sucesivos es el condicional [switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Por lo que veo en tu código `paq` hace referencia a un `enum`, dado el caso, podrías hacer lo siguiente utilizando `switch`

```
var paq = TuEnum.Lunes;
switch (paq)
    {          
        case TuEnum.Lunes:
        //Aquí iría la lógica en caso de ser lunes
        break;

        case TuEnum.Martes:
        //Aquí en caso de ser martes
        break;

        default:
        //Por último aquí iría la lógica si ninguno de los otros casos se cumplió.
        break;
    }
```

De todos modos, te recomiendo que leas la **[documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)**, que no es muy larga, usa varios ejemplos muy fáciles de entender.

---

En cuanto a la segunda parte de tu código, donde evaluas, por ejemplo:

```
if (!paq.aplicaTransporte)
this.transporte.Visible = false;
```

Estas utilizando un `if` completamente innecesario, sería lo mismo escribir `this.transporte.Visible = paq.aplicaTransporte;`

---

**EDIT**: Para usar [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) en lugar de `Boolean` deberías hacer lo siguiente:

Modificar la definición de tu clase por algo como lo siguiente

```
public class PaqueteTour
{
     public Dias DiaDeLaSemana;
     public enum Dias { Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado,Domingo };
}
```

Luego para setearlo, lo harías de la siguiente manera: `DiaDeLaSemana = Dias.Martes` por ejemplo.

Por último, al momento que chequear su valor, podrías hacerlo con el `switch` como explique más arriba, o también con un `if`, que sería de la siguiente manera

```
if(DiaDeLaSemana == Dias.Martes)
{
    //Lógica si es martes
}
```

Comment: Los atributos Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, etc, son atributos por separados, acabo de aactuliza el post para mostrar la estructura de mi clase

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Hay algo que te impida definir un `enum`? me parece muchísimo más lógico

Comment: No de hecho me parece una buena idea tu respuesta, solo queria saber si aun con esa estrctura de la clase yo puedo crear un enum?

Comment: Cuando inicio un enum, todo el codigo que esta debado de, me marca como error, ya cheque la sintaxis pero aun me da el mismo error

Comment: intenté crear un enum pero me marca error

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Ahí modifique la respuesta, si seguis sin entender como hacerlo decime

Comment: Ahora si ya entendí mejor gracias hermano

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez un placer

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar `bitwise` para guardar multi seleccion en un solo campo.

No se si conoces como funciona este concepto, pero basicamente se basa en guardar los valores 1,2,4,8,16 etc

[Enum, Flags and bitwise operators](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/)

[Create Enumeration as Bit Flags](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/10/make-your-enumeration-to-bit-flags.html)

entonces podrias tener un enum para la semana como ser

```
enum SemanaEnum{
   Lunes = 1,
   Marte = 2,
   Miercoles = 4,
   Jueves = 8,
   Viernes = 16,
   Sabado = 32,
   Domingo = 128,
}
```

entonces usando el `OR` logico puede unir varios de estos valores en un solo campo, no necesitas una propiedad dia de la semana

```
SemanaEnum result = SemanaEnum.Martes | SemanaEnum.Jueves;
```

La idea es que despues cuando evalues puedas determinar si esta esa seleccion o no

```
if ((paq.Semana & SemanaEnum.Marte) == SemanaEnum.Marte){
   //codigo
}
```

por supuesto viendolo asi no evita escribir lo if, pero si un Dictionary como ser

```
Dictionary<SemanaEnum, object> lista = new Dictionary<SemanaEnum, object>(){
   {SemanaEnum.Lunes, this.lu},
   {SemanaEnum.Marte, this.ma},
    //resto
}

foreach(var item in lista){
  if ((paq.Semana & item.Key) == item.Key){
      item.Value.Attributes.Add("class", "select");
   }
}
```

Asi evitas los if y haces tu codigo ams dinamico

Nota: Puse el value del Dictionary como object porque no sabia de que tipo se trata, pero lo correcto es que pongas el tipo que corresponda